# How to convert documentation of Qt console application and its arguments' description from c++ Qt main code into an external format

Tags: c++, qt5, documentation-generation

Assume an Qt c++ application using the QCommandLineParser to define and process its arguments and options according to the typical pattern (mentioned bellow). Is there a way to convert the description of the particular arguments and options from the source code into a human readable format (html, rtf, ...). (I am looking for something similar like e.g. doxygen, to allow to 'reuse' the description from source code in an external documentation webpage).

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QCommandLineParser parser;
parser.addHelpOption();
parser.addVersionOption();
parser.addPositionalArgument("lorem1", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.");
parser.addOption(QCommandLineOption("lorem2", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", "value"));
```

Thanks.

I apologize in advance for the case that the question duplicates some already answered ones. Please link existing answers, since I am not able to find any relevant one.

Comment: maybe qdoc: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/01-qdoc-manual.html

Comment: I would run application with `--help` and then try to find some parser for the output. Since documentation style is Linux like I wouldn't be surprised if there is some tool to make this output nice looking. @eyllanesc you have misunderstood question (it is not code documentation but program parameters documentation).

Comment: @MarekR I pointed out qdoc because of the following line:  *...like e.g. doxygen, to allow to 'reuse' **the description from source code**...*

Comment: @MarekR: thanks for the hint, your interpretation is correct. I do not search for code documentation parser, but rather a documentation of the console arguments. I am not sure if there is a way using qdoc. The question can also be rewritten: "Is there a recommended way how to write description of Qt application arguments once and use the description twice (in source code and for documentation purposes)? E.g. markdown to html and markdown to source code to include in main.cpp?